# undefined error 0 when open the zip file generate by rust

Tags: rust

I am using this rust code to generate the zip file in macOS 13.3.1:

```
use std::{path::Path, fs::File};
use zip::{ZipWriter, write::FileOptions};

fn main() {
    let file = File::create("/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/archive.zip").unwrap();
    let mut zip = ZipWriter::new(file);
    let folder_path = Path::new("/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server");
    visit_folder(folder_path, &mut zip, "").unwrap();
    zip.finish().unwrap();
}

fn visit_folder(path: &Path, zip: &mut ZipWriter<File>, parent: &str) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    for entry in path.read_dir()? {
        let entry = entry?;
        let file_path = entry.path();
        let file_name = file_path.file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy().into_owned();
        let zip_path = format!("{}{}/{}", parent, path.file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy(), file_name);
        if file_path.is_dir() {
            visit_folder(&file_path, zip, &zip_path)?;
        } else {
            let mut file = File::open(&file_path)?;
            let options = FileOptions::default()
                .compression_method(zip::CompressionMethod::Deflated)
                .unix_permissions(0o755);
            zip.start_file(zip_path, options)?;
            std::io::copy(&mut file, zip)?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

this code works fine, but when I opened the zip file that generate by rust. shows error `Error 0 - undefined error 0`. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? This is the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git", branch = "diesel2.0", features = [
    "model",
    "common",
    "rwconfig",
    "texhub"
] }
zip = "0.6"
```

Comment: Maybe replacing `unwrap()` with better error handling would give you more insight about the problem.

Comment: There is no error when using rust to compress the folder. @mkrieger1

Comment: The archive in inside the directory to be archived. Isn't that problematic? Or maybe `add_directory()` is needed before `start_file()` creates something inside such a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this code works fine

On my machine this code does *not* work fine: I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:10:45:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: Other, error: "Large file option has not been set" }
```

That is because as prog-fh noted the archive is created inside the directory which gets zipped. This means it will get added to itself.

Because `archive.zip` is brand new it will likely be iterated last by `read_dir`, and because the directory is quite large by the time it gets to itself `archive.zip` will almost certainly contain enough data that zip-rs needs to flush when writing it to itself, meaning you get an infinite-size file as it keeps writing new data that it then compresses back into itself. This results in `archive.zip` exceeding 4GB, and because zip-rs does not enable zip64 by default it faults there. The `archive.zip` file exists regardless, it's just garbage.

Possibly in your case the IO or directory iteration order is such that it stops writing at one point, but the archive will likely be improperly terminated. Or maybe you've just silenced the output somehow.

The solution is to either create the zip file outside of that directory, or modify the code so it does not get picked up.

Incidentally it's not entirely clear what

> when I opened the zip file that generate by rust. shows error Error 0 - undefined error 0

Means (opened with what?) but you can use `unzip -t` to `t`est archives. That might provide richer and easier to investigate errors.